# why are my own commits to my own branch creating diffs in eGit (using eclipse with eGit to bitbucket)

Tags: git, eclipse, bitbucket, egit

Im going to post this question in a "for dummies" format as I am, in fact, a dummy.

Here is the process Ive been following and its killing me

I AM THE ONLY ONE WORKING ON THIS BRANCH

1. Pull Master
2. Create branch A
3. Make changes to Branch A
4. Commit and Push Branch A
5. Hold code review...changes are required from code review
6. Pull Branch A (eGit reports no changes)
7. update Branch A with required changes
8. Commit and Push Branch A
   **** egit rejects and reports non-fast forward.  eGit shows the same number of changes in orgin/Branch A now as i made in remote/Branch A
9. Branch A pull - eGit now pulls a change and creates a merge commit
10. i can now successfully push my change (although I have to amend the merge commit message due to formatting requirement)

Comment: On server side, there might be a Git hook that modifies a commit, e.g. by adding something to the commit message. If you did a push, verify whether you have the same commit ID/hash locally vs. remotely. If it's not the same, the commit has been modified. Otherwise, please tell what step 5 means (what you do exactly in or outside of Eclipse?). In step 8 disable _Ignore White Space Where Applicable_ which is enabled by default. By the way, it's up to you whether you merge or rebase (for a better readable history choose rebase).

Comment: It would help if you showed the exact commands you used in each step, and the output. Especially steps 6,7,8. Also, show the output of `git status` after step 8. Also, look at the commit(s) that step 9 is merging in, and that should give you some pretty good insight as to what happened.

Comment: Without more information, my top theory is that in step 8 you amended your top commit rather than creating a new one. In that case you need to force push in step 8 instead of regular push.

Comment: For clarification, 

* - Im using eGit not Git.  I could guess at the underlying commands but im not sure exactly what they are

@TTT
* Step 6 - would just be a git pull while on the branch (but nothing comes down, as the remote and local are the same).

* Step 7 - No git command, im talking about making suggested changes to my code

*Step 8 - Literally add modified file to stage, Commit, Push to head

The only commit that Im modifying is the merge commit after Im forced to repull the unchanged remote branch.

Comment: OK. I think there may be a terminal you can run commands in, such as `git status`. Or you can run Git commands from a command prompt outside (if Git is installed out of Eclipse.) In general, if you start to use Git heavily you might find yourself wishing to run certain advanced commands that can only be run from a command line, especially if you are troubleshooting. I assume though that right in Eclipse you can view the history of your branch so you can see what the second parent of the new merge commit is. Looking at that commit should help you determine where it come from.

Comment: I figured it out @TTT - dont laugh, but eGit has a button in the Commit Message view that allows you to amend, the message on your HEAD commit.  Like a dope, ive been using it to pull in the text I want so that I didnt have to retype it without realizing that I was actually creating a new commit on the amend.  Ill close this question

Comment: @TTT If you would know EGit, you wouldn't say that. I guess it's not just me, but I want to use advanced features of Git without having to learn cryptic commands first. Think of the _Git Interactive Rebase_ view, for example.

Comment: @TheUltimateHack Please close this question by providing a self-answer or deleting the question.

Comment: @howlger EGit stands out among most UI tools if it can do interactive rebase. Can EGit also do `git rebase <commit-id> <branch> --onto <another-branch>`? That's probably the command my team uses the most that AFAIK no UI tools offers. But even with interactive rebase, I wouldn't consider `-i` to be "cryptic", and once the editor pops up the options are right there in front of you. At some point I'll try out the EGit interactive rebase to see how it feels compared to a text editor, but I've found most developers pick up interactive rebase quickly using the command line...

Comment: Closing this question due to OP accidentally amending instead of adding a new commit in step 8, which is why the push failed.

Comment: @TTT You are free to stick to the command line for everything and forever, even for tasks that can be done better in a different way. But please stop spreading FUD about something you don't know.

Comment: @howlger I don't know why you say I'm spreading FUD? Do you mean this statement, "if you start to use Git heavily you might find yourself wishing to run certain advanced commands that can only be run from a command line, especially if you are troubleshooting"? If that's FUD then ok, I stand by it. It's not about EGit/Eclipse but just a general statement. I apologize if that offended you regarding EGit specifically. Besides, general Git knowledge solved this question and it probably didn't need any tags beyond the "git" tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253377/discussion-between-ttt-and-howlger).

Comment: @TTT Contrary to what you say, you can do advanced Git stuff with EGit/JGit. There were even things that were first implemented in JGit and then took over by git-core. Most people aren't okay with spreading FUD and _"I apologize if that offended"_ is a non-apology.

Comment: @howlger I agree that wasn't a good apology; I apologize for that. ;) But I never said you can't do advanced Git stuff with EGit/JGit. I just said you *might* find yourself wishing to run *certain* advanced commands that can only be run from the command line. I didn't even specify a UI tool with that statement. All I meant by that is people generally shouldn't be afraid to use the command line because sometimes it comes in handy. This is true regardless of what UI tools you typically use.

Comment: @TTT (a) Please respect the decision which software someone uses. Software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Everyone knows there is a command line Git, so don't bother telling it. (b) Command line Git for rarely used advanced commands is a pain. Every time you have to re-learn it and you have to pay attention on how rather on what you want to do. Do you want people to understand the concepts or memorize command line commands? The command line Git is also the opposite for what the first letter of IDE stands for.

Answer (score 0):

figued out that in eGit i was accidentally creating a merge commit using the ammed button.  I thought the ammed button was just allowing me to edit the message, not create a new commit